# GDI+ shows artifact when drawing rectangles side-by-side with scale factor

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

Using GDI+ to draw two rectangles side-by-side, if I apply a scale factor to have a zoom effect, an artifact appears between the rectangles in some scale factors.

I have the following code to show the problem:

```
var scale = (float)(numericUpDown1.Value)/100.0f;

var g = e.Graphics;
var b = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
var rect1 = new Rectangle(10, 40, 100, 100);
var rect2 = new Rectangle(110, 40, 100, 100);

g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

g.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

g.FillRectangle(b, rect1);
g.FillRectangle(b, rect2);
```

Using this code and setting the "numericUpDown1" to 100, I get the following:

[image: No scaling]

Setting the scale to 125, I get a line between the rectangles:

[image: Scaling 125%]

Scaling to pretty much any value that is not a multiple of 10 gives this problem. Looking close on the line, it seems to be some anti-aliasing effect. **I can't remove the anti-aliasing** because in my real scenario the rectangles might be polygons with non-straight lines.

[image: Zoom on the artifact]

I've tried many things, like toggling the PixelOffsetMode, CompositingQuality, Antialiasing, but nothing works. My goal is to have something in the same level of quality of what MS PowerPoint does.

Comment: This is odd... did some testing with this and not all scales render this artifact. 20% 100% and 150% are fine; however 25%, 75% and 125% all produced the artifact.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. I believe that there is simply a scaling issue since you are trying to render 2 rectangles abutted to each other. I increased the width of rect1 by one and there is no issue. Maybe draw a border around the rectangles ???

Comment: Have you tried: `g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor`?

Comment: @BartoszKP just tried, didn't make any effect.

Comment: @IAbstract I might try that, but it will require some extra effort as using the same rects to call DrawRectangle creates a larger rectangle

Comment: The 2nd rectangles left side is at 110 x 125% = 137.5 pixels.  Of course you want GDI+ to just round it to 137 or 138 (which?) but that's not the way GDI likes to do it.  Because that would get you into the nightmare of floating point rounding.  Where the first rectangle's right side happens to round down and the 2nd rectangle's left side rounds up and leaves a very visible white gap.  You definitely don't want *that* problem.  There's no perfect answer, you gave GDI+ a hard time to do it right and you see that.

Comment: @korbes do you mean the **anti-aliasing effect** you don't want to remove is enabled by `SmoothingMode = HighQuality`? Because removing that works but it may not be what you want.

Comment: @KingKing yes, removing SmoothingMode solves the problem, but in my real scenario I can't remove it.

Comment: @HansPassant any ideas on how other software like PowerPoint solve the problem? I can do the same thing there (put two rectangles side-by-side) and play with the zoom as much as I want, and there's no artifact.

Comment: @korbes The most common approach to avoid such problems is vector graphics, instead of raster.

Comment: Why can Powerpoint do this?  It is a program that was worked on by hundreds of programmers for 20+ years.  It doesn't use GDI+  It is like looking at a photo in Vogue magazine, how come my wife doesn't look like this?  I like the her anti-aliasing, suits me well ;)

Comment: @HansPassant No, it's not anything like "emergence magic". Even one programmer in much less than 20 years can implement simple vector graphics algorithms :)

Comment: Yup, the OP's problem too. Surely it is possible.

Comment: It won't work with GDI+ because that does draws sequentially, and applies anti-aliasing to each draw individually. To get smoothing while avoiding things like this, you have to draw at a larger resolution and scale the result down. (BTW, modern versions of PowerPoint DO use GDI+, but since 2007 office ships its own copy of it named ogl.dll.)

Comment: @VincentPovirk if you make your comment the answer I'd like to accept it.